# Cypher paged-listing query optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

We have the following data model in a Neo4j database.
Nodes with label **Post**, and nodes with **User**

The relation between **Post** and **User** is *(Post)-[:POSTED_BY]->(User)*. It indicates that a post was created by the given user.

On Post nodes, there is a property named `sort_order` which gives the order by which post nodes should be retrieved. The `sort_order` is **unique** and **index-backed**; a unique constraint is enforced in the schema.

In a listing request, I need to get the posts for a given user ordered by `sort_order`, and in pages of 10 (for example)

According to [Neo4j Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/advanced-example/#advanced-query-tuning-example-index-backed-order-by), the order operation is skipped by the planner because the nodes are already ordered based on the index of the selected property `sort_order`. This limits the database hits and time required to complete the query by the selected page size. This applies perfectly for such a query:

```
MATCH (post:Post)
where post.sort_order > 0
return post
order by post.sort_order desc
limit 10
```

if the hint `post.sort_order > 0` is given.

Once I need to retrieve the posts by a given **User**, the query will fetch all Post nodes related to the selected User ordering them in memory, and returning the current page (of 10 records). After profiling the following required query, it appears to ignore the index.

```
MATCH (post:Post)-[:IN]->(user:User {id: 3})
where post.sort_order > 0
return post
order by post.sort_order desc
limit 10
```

Is there are any hidden problems in the query or the data model ?

Or, if any optimizations can be done to the query, data model, or indices.

The used neo4j version is 3.5.23

Comment: You can evaluate the performance with EXPLAIN/PROFILE as explained here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/#how-do-i-profile-a-query

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher planner probably determined (using the server's DB statistics) that it was generally more efficient to execute your last query by looking up the `User` node (hopefully you have an `:User(id)` index to help with that), getting its related `Post` nodes, and then sorting.

If you were successful at forcing the planner to use your `:Post(sort_order)` index instead, then the execution would probably be *much less* efficient. That is because the query would still have to get and evaluate the related `User` nodes for (presumably almost) every `Post`.

Comment: Yes, that sounds logical. But both ways will be costly in terms of speed and memory, if a User node has thousands of Post nodes attached.

Is there any suggestions for better pagination of post nodes an a given user node ?